# Group by not showing null values

Tags: mysql, group-by

EDIT : [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2fc5/2/0)

Here is my table errand :

```
user_id | date       | hour  | done
1       | 2016-01-01 | 08:00 | 08:03:07
1       | 2016-01-01 | 09:00 | 09:05:07
2       | 2016-01-01 | 11:00 | 11:07:05
2       | 2016-01-01 | 11:10 | 11:18:01
3       | 2016-01-01 | 9:00 | null
3       | 2016-01-01 | 10:00 | null
3       | 2016-01-01 | 10:05 | null
```

I want to get the last errand of each user :

```
user_id | date       | hour  | done
1       | 2016-01-01 | 09:00 | 09:05:07
2       | 2016-01-01 | 11:10 | 11:18:05
3       | 2016-01-01 | 10:05 | null
```

So I have used GROUP BY like and it works :

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(done) done FROM errand WHERE done = '2016-06-01' GROUP BY user_id;
```

It shows me :

```
user_id | done
1       | 09:05:07
2       | 11:18:05
3       | null
```

But, the problem is I can't display the hour and date by adding it in SELECT because I get this : (Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ... which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by).

So I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM errand e JOIN (
    SELECT user_id u, MAX(done) d
    FROM errand WHERE date = '2016-06-01'
    GROUP BY user_id
) x on x.a = e.user_id AND x.b = e.done;
```

But it only shows me rows where done is not null :

```
user_id | date       | hour  | done
1       | 2016-01-01 | 09:00 | 09:05:07
2       | 2016-01-01 | 11:10 | 11:18:05
```

How can I do to get the 3rd user where done is null ?

Comment: I'd store date and time as a single entity. And I'd store `done` as a TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [null-safe equal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator so that comparing `NULL` with `NULL` will match.

```
SELECT e.* FROM errand e JOIN (
    SELECT user_id u, MAX(done) d
    FROM errand WHERE date = '2016-06-01'
    GROUP BY user_id
) x on x.u = e.user_id AND x.d <=> e.done;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3af60/2)

Comment: It returns me every line inside the table. When I put `=` I get 2 results, but the `<=>` a lot more

Comment: Strange, because on my MySQL, I got this : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/23/1465575944-005.png : Do you have an idea why the result is different ?

Comment: If you duplicate the last line in your SQLFIDDLE and change the date, it will show you two times the user 3 : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2fc5/1/0

Comment: That will happen any time you have have two rows with the same `user_id` and the maximum value of `done` for that ID. How is it supposed to choose which one to return?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT user_id u, MAX(done) d
    FROM errand WHERE date = '2016-01-01'
    GROUP BY user_id 
) x 
LEFT OUTER JOIN errand e on x.u = e.user_id AND x.d = e.done;
```

Comment: I get : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'e.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: GROUP BY courier_id - is it existing column? I changed it to user_id, aslo changed aliases in ON clause. Is it still giving an error?

Comment: Sorry It was a mistake, it is user_id column instead of courier_id